# How Destructor executes?

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, destructor, new-operator

I did practicals on Destructor but when compile this program I don't know why the output not come as I thought.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class aaa
{
   private:
   static int x;
   int code;
   public:
   /*after constructor executes 3 times the value of "code" becomes 103*/
  aaa()   
  {
    code=x;
    cout<<"Default Constructor"<<endl;
    x++;
  } 
  ~aaa() 
  {
    cout<<"Destructor of "<<code<<endl;
  } 
};
int aaa::x=101;
int main() 
{
   aaa *p;
   p=new aaa[3];
   delete []p;
   return 0;
 }
```

Output is:

```
Default Constructor
Default Constructor
Default Constructor
Destructor of 103
Destructor of 102 
Destructor of 101
```

while I thought it was going to be this:

```
101
102
103
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know why the output not come as I thought.

Because the objets are destructed in reverse order of construction: First constructed, last destructed.

The destructors are called in the *reverse order* of the constructors' calls, which explains the behavior you see.

So when you dynamically allocate memory with `new[]` for your array, the constructors are called in the natural order (the one you expect), but when `delete[]` is called to free that memory, every element of the array gets destructed in the reverse order.

Read more in [Why destructors are not called in reverse order for array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31246000/why-destructors-are-not-called-in-reverse-order-for-array-of-objects)

---

> What happens if i write `delete p` instead of `delete []p`, so ho many times Destructor is called?

C++ requires that you delete arrays with `delete[]` and delete non-arrays with `delete`. So I can't answer that. Read more in [Delete and delete [] are the same when deleting arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953457/delete-and-delete-are-the-same-when-deleting-arrays)

Comment: and what happens if i write delete p instead of delete []p, so ho many times Destructor is called

Comment: @AmanWarudkar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953457/delete-and-delete-are-the-same-when-deleting-arrays

Comment: @AmanWarudkar updated my answer, hope this helps! Do not forget to *accept* an answer. Curious thanks for the link and nice answer BTW.

Answer (score 3):

Destruction happens in the opposite order of construction, that is why you see the destructor for 103 called first.

i.e. When you allocate the array, `new[]` constructs the objects in one direction and then when you call `delete[]` the objects are destroyed from the end of the array.

See [@StoryTeller's answer for a quote from the C++ standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44798850/5501675) regarding this behavior.

Comment: and what happens if i write delete p instead of delete []p, so ho many times Destructor is called

Comment: @AmanWarudkar see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953457/delete-and-delete-are-the-same-when-deleting-arrays you should always delete arrays allocated with `new[]` with `delete[]`

Answer (score 2):

Destructors are invoked in reverse order to object initialization, and that is true for arrays destroyed by `delete[]` as well:

[[expr.delete/6]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.delete#6)

> If the value of the operand of the delete-expression is not a null
>   pointer value, the delete-expression will invoke the destructor (if
>   any) for the object or the elements of the array being deleted. **In the
>   case of an array, the elements will be destroyed in order of
>   decreasing address (that is, in reverse order of the completion of
>   their constructor;** see [class.base.init]).

Comment: Beat me to the standard quote!